# Accessing AWS APIs from within a lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I'm writing my first lambda function (in Python), and I'm a little confused about how credentials are supposed to work in the lambda environment.  I'm trying to retrieve a secret (for Aurora database access) from the aws secrets api, using their example code which looks something like this (I've stripped out all the error handling for brevity):

```
def get_secret():
    secret_name = 'dbtest-postgres-secret'
    region_name = 'us-east-2'

    session = boto3.session.Session()                                                                                                                                                          
    client = session.client(                                                                                                                                                                   
        service_name='secretsmanager',                                                                                                                                                         
        region_name=region_name                                                                                                                                                                
    )                                                                                                                                                                                          

    get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(                                                                                                                                   
        SecretId=secret_name                                                                                                                                                               
    )                                                                                                                                                                                      

    secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']

    return secret
```

This works fine locally in an environment in which I have my normal AWS credentials, but returns None without raising any errors when running as part of a lambda function.  I'm using it like this:

```
def handler(event, context):
    secret = get_secret()
    assert secret is not None
```

And it's failing at that `assert` statement:

```
{
  "errorType": "AssertionError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/dbtest.py\", line nn, in handler\n    assert secret is not None\n"
  ]
}
```

I assumed that by assigning a role to the lambda function with appropriate permissions (`AmazonRDSDataFullAccess`, which includes permissions to access the secrets manager) that everything would be set. Do I need to provide explicit credentials (e.g., an access key and secret) to the lambda function?

Comment: i'am wondering why you didn't see an AccessDeniedError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to give explicit credentials, the lambda will get the credentials from the role you assigned to it. What is the secret you are asking for, because the `AmazonRDSDataFullAccess` only has access to secrets at `rds-db-credentials/*`.

Comment: The secret is called "dbtest-postgres-secret".  Are you saying it needs to have a name prefixed with `rds-db-credentials/`?

Comment: That's correct. In order for that particular policy to work you would need to do that. If you need a different set of secrets you should specify the name(s) (or pattern) in a policy that you create.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!